# How to select the oldest table in a database by create_time?

Tags: mysql, date, sql-order-by

I have a MySQL database with multiple tables created at different times and I would like to find the oldest table in the database by "CREATE_TIME". But I also need to convert the "CREATE_TIME" into UNIX_TIMESTAMP. I've already researched a few other questions on Stack Overflow but they only describe how to get the date only. I need to find the oldest table in the database by it's full time stamp or Unix time stamp.

So far I have tried these two queries but neither return the oldest table.

```
SELECT MAX(create_time) create_time 
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_schema = 'notes' 
ORDER BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(create_time) DESC 
LIMIT 1

SELECT MAX(create_time) 
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_schema = 'notes' 
GROUP BY TABLE_SCHEMA 
ORDER BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(create_time) DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Also as an added bit of information, The database does not put the tables in order automatically from oldest to newest in either ASC or DESC. So trying to sort using either of those never finds the oldest table. It only finds the first oldest table it finds and not the actual oldest table in the DB.

Comment: rather than `max` use `min`

Comment: _“The database does not put the tables in order automatically from oldest to newest in either ASC or DESC. So trying to sort using either of those never finds the oldest table.”_ - no idea what you are trying to say here. Order _always_ only exists, after you _specified_ what order you want to get the records in. If you want them by create_time, then order by create_time. This has nothing to do with “the database” putting anything in any sort of default order.

Answer (score 0):

> select the oldest table in a database by `create_time`

I think you want:

```
SELECT t.*, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(create_time) create_timestamp
FROM information_schema.tables t
WHERE table_schema = 'notes' 
ORDER BY create_time
LIMIT 1
```

This gives you oldest record from `information_schema.tables`, as defined by `create_time`, with an additional column that contains the corresponding unix timestamp.